# In Swift, is there a better way to initialize a "get" only variable?

Tags: ios, swift, accessor

Say I have a class, `MyClass`, and it can be in either a valid or invalid state. So I keep track of this with a bool called `isValid`. I want this value initialized to `false` until the class's `initialize` function is called. The `initialize` (and a corresponding `reset` function) will directly be able to change the value of the `isValid` bool. This is what I have set up so far:

```
class MyClass {

  private var _isValid: Bool = false
  var isValid: Bool {
    get { return _isValid }
  }

// any required init functions

  func initialize() {
    // init stuff
    _isValid = true
  }

  func reset() {
    // reset stuff
    _isValid = false
  }

}
```

So is this the best way to do it, or is there any way I can remove the second private var and somehow allow just the class functions to modify a read only public facing variable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just make your setter private. See [Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3).

```
class MyClass {

    private(set) var isValid = false

    func initialize() {
        // init stuff
        self.isValid = true
    }

    func reset() {
        // reset stuff
        self.isValid = false
    }        
}
```

Comment: Yes! I didn't know about that keyword, but that's exactly what I'm looking for and I don't have to have a duplicate private var anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome thank you!!! not sure how I missed that option

Answer (score -1):

Another way for a **get-only property**

```
public var isValid: Bool {
   return true
}

isValid = false // Cannot assign to property: 'isValid' is a get-only property
```

Comment: This is a computed property and it does not meet the requirements. The requirement is a get only property that can be internally modified, as specified by:

"The initialize (and a corresponding reset function) will directly be able to change the value of the isValid bool."

Using `private(set)`, as pointed out by Rob, is the best solution.

Comment: @TimFuqua For the specific use case, of course. I just wanted to give another option for those who come across this thread.